# Unable to create TreeListView using object model

Tags: c#, objectlistview, treelistview

I am trying to make a treelistview that displays information kinda like this

```
ComputerName(String)
  -> OS(String)
  -> Drives(String)
      -> DriveLabel(String)
```

I am not sure why but I am unable to create the tree view based on my object model, what could be going on? I've been messing with this for a while now and perhaps I've just confused my self but it shouldn't be this hard to use this control....any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my class

```
public class ComputerInfo
{
   public string ComputerName { get; set; }
   public string OS { get; set; }
   public string Pingable { get; set; }

   public List<string> Memory { get; set; }
   public List<string> Drives { get; set; }

   public ComputerInfo()
   {
      this.Memory = new List<string>();
      this.Drives = new List<string>();
   }
}
```

From what i read, I need to place delegate code during loadup

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   this.treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x)
   {
      return true;
   };
   this.treeListView1.ChildrenGetter = delegate(object x)
   {
      NetworkDefrag.DefragClass.ComputerInfo pc = x as NetworkDefrag.DefragClass.ComputerInfo;
      return pc.Drives;
   };
}
```

and here is my code for the actual work

```
public void work2(string line)
{
   NetworkDefrag.DefragClass.ComputerInfo computer = new DefragClass.ComputerInfo();
   computer.ComputerName = line;

   //1
   bool pingable = false;
   Task pingTask = new Task(() => pingable = PingHost(line));
   pingTask.Start();
   pingTask.Wait();

   //2
   if (pingable.Equals(true))
   {
      TreeNode servernameNode = new TreeNode(line);
      computer.Pingable = "Server is online";

      //3
      //var drives = GetDrives(line, domaintextBox3.Text, usernametextBox1.Text, passwordtextBox2.Text);
      List<string> drives = new List<string>();
      Task drivesTask = new Task(() => drives = GetDrives(line, domaintextBox3.Text, usernametextBox1.Text, passwordtextBox2.Text));

      computer.Drives.AddRange(drives);

      drivesTask.Start();
      drivesTask.Wait();

      //4
      foreach (string drive in drives)
      {
         //TreeNode driveNode = new TreeNode(drive);

         //5
         string fragNeeded = string.Empty;
         //var fragNeeded = GetFragPercentage(line, drive, usernametextBox1.Text, passwordtextBox2.Text);
         Task fragNeededTask = new Task(() => fragNeeded = GetFragPercentage(line, drive, usernametextBox1.Text, passwordtextBox2.Text));
         fragNeededTask.Start();
         fragNeededTask.Wait();
         //var fragPercentage = GetFragPercentage(line, drive, usernametextBox1.Text, passwordtextBox2.Text);
         if (fragNeeded.Equals("True"))
         {
            TreeNode driveNode = new TreeNode(drive);
            driveNode.BackColor = Color.Red;
            driveNode.Checked = true;
            servernameNode.Checked = true;
            InsertIntoTree2(servernameNode, driveNode);
         }
         if (fragNeeded.Equals("False"))
         {
            TreeNode driveNode = new TreeNode(drive);
            driveNode.BackColor = Color.Green;
            InsertIntoTree2(servernameNode, driveNode);
         }
      }
      Servers.Add(computer);
      InsertIntoTree(servernameNode);

      //treeListView1.UpdateObjects(Servers);
      treeListView1.RefreshObject(computer);

   }

}
```

UPDATE:

I was not assigning the Aspect value in column editor but now that I have that fixed, the nodes now have text! My issue is actually with the children nodes (the drive nodes), those are not showing up as expected (expandable)
[image]

Comment: It does add nodes but there is no label, I can only expand empty nodes..

Comment: Are you saying your nodes should have text but instead they are empty?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the structure is created using my object model (computer) but the strings are not displayed

Comment: Is there a reason your using tasks, ie your just waiting for them to complete anyway?, also have you used a break point and checked if the drives list actually has names in it?

Comment: I'm using Tasks as a way of threading my application, with you asking these questions it has me thinking that I could redo my code a bit to better handle threads. I figured out why my node had no text, I did not assign the Aspect value under column designer. I am having issues displaying the drives nodes (multiple drives per computer), it shows up as list object and not actual items..